# What does this host means ' ::1 '

Tags: networking, security

To secure my mysql server, I checked the list of users :

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host,Password FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| User             | Host      | Password                                  |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost | ******************************************|
| root             | 127.0.0.1 | ******************************************|
| root             | ::1       | ******************************************|
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | ******************************************|
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

root and debian-sys-maint are using localhost/127.0.0.1 as hosts.

But I don't understand what does `::1` notation means ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

::1 is the ipv6 version of 127.0.0.1

Comment: -It's Just one of many ways to describe the IP address of localhost in the new IPv6 version, and as was generally commented these new commands to IPv6 has its own new version and have the ping that is eventually widely used with IPv4 version, have the ping6 to be used for the IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 5):

The address `::1` (or `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001` with all fields written out) is an IP version 6 address and specifies the loopback address in host scope. So technically, it is the same as the IP version 4 address `127.0.0.1`.